# Why Is my SVG getting cropped instead of scaled?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

This is my SVG Tag:

```
<svg 
baseprofile="tiny" 
fill="#ececec" 
height="857" 
stroke="black" 
stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke-width=".2" 
version="1.2" 
viewbox="0 0 2000 857" 
width="2000" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

The problem is that when I change the width of this component in CSS it will crop the image instead of scaling it. Changing the height and width to 100% didn't work either.

This worked perfectly fine in standard HTML and CSS but when I moved it into react it stopped working. I have been searching on how to fix this for hours only Scale() in CSS has worked but I can't get that to scale with the window size.

Here is the React Code

```
import React from 'react'

function map() {
    return (
        <div>
          <SVG>...</SVG>
        </div>
      )
}
```

export default map

and also this tag is used inside of this:

```
function book() {
    return (
        <body>
            <div id="map-container">
                <Map/>
            </div>
        </body>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you post your react code? I'm only asking because you said it was working fine in html/css. How are you importing the svg into your react app? Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Sure I can but I really only put it inside the return().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understand what was happening here was the `viewbox`.

Your viewbox was right but  to use it in html you have to use `view-box` instead of `viewbox` like you have in your code example.

In react.js you have to use it like this: `viewBox` because using react.js you have to replace the `kebab-case` for `camelCase` in markup variables.

Here is the codesandbox solving it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dhawan-pwmmq?file=/src/App.js

You can modify the width and the height to any value, the svg will still be responsive!

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Comment: Changing the View Box isn't fixing it, it worked before with those viewbox dimensions though before I put it into react.

Comment: could you upload the svg somewhere?

Comment: Or replicate the error at codesandbox or something similar? You can upload the svg data too!

Comment: Sure thing, this should work: https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-butterfly-tr7x4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: If you could send a codesandbox back that fixes the error that would be super helpful. @Martin

Comment: it helped a lot! I modified the answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to fix this for like 8-10 hours now and all it was was just one letter that needed to be capatalized.